# d3.js Internet Explorer svg group onclick function

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg, d3.js

I'm at my wits end with a strange problem in IE that doesn't seem to be plaguing other browsers. I have several functions that are bound to an svg g element with different listeners (mouseover, mouseup, mouseout). When the mousedown function is triggered, it causes the browser to hang (it is no longer possible to click on anything)- but the JavaScript doesn't seem to hang at all! The force-directed graph continues to happily run the tick function.

To make matters more odd, when I trigger the mousedown function using a normal html anchor, it works fine, and everything progresses.

Prior to this problem, the site hung quite spectacularly when I had another mousedown function attached to it. Because of removing that, I've been able to get a little farther. However, I was wondering if anyone else had similar problems using simultaneously triggered functions for svg on IE.

This works fine in Chrome and Firefox by the way.

Thanks!

**Related:** This is non-functional on IE 11 with Windows 7. Windows 8 works though, oddly enough.

**Update:** This now exists in a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/skellig/ad8t8rg0/. The major problem is in the function below:

```
 function highlight(Index)
 {
 var get=d3nodes[0]
 var NodeUse=get[Index];

 d3.select(NodeUse).attr("href", "#highlightNode");

 }
```

The hanging is a little bit worse on the jsfiddle. You can contrast it to playing it on Chrome, where it works fine. It might have trouble in Safari, however.

Comment: What version of IE is this?

Comment: Oh, good call! This is IE 11 on Windows 7. And oddly enough, it works alright on Windows 8, if that helps.

Comment: I think we'll need a code sample to debug this, this is a fairly specific problem.

Comment: That's fair enough. I'll adapt it to a jsfiddle and see if I can get a reproducible effect.

Comment: The jsfiddle turned out to be too convoluted, but see the latest comment. I will continue to try and get the fiddle to work, or debug the 1006 error. Thanks.

Comment: I have distilled the problem to the rest(); and the highlightnode() functions, both of which seem to be causing the issue. Interestingly, if you dynamically swap the href of the svg object externally it doesn't seem to have a problem. However, if it's triggering its own swap, it has an issue. Curiouser and curiouser.

Comment: More update: the problem is in a clash between the energy it takes to call tip.hide() and rest() (perhaps rest() is still being called which causes some kind of activity overflow?) Either ways, if you throw the rest() function on a timeout and trigger the tip.hide() before the timeout goes off, then the setup is good. If anyone knows of a good way not to make these functions clash, that would be excellent. Otherwise I will post my fix when I have it.

Comment: Latest is that none of the mouse listeners are the problem, but if the mouse is present overtop of a svg href that is being swapped, the program hangs and the mouse is unuseable. Running out of workaround ideas at this point.

Comment: I'm running into this now as well. Any progress or workaround to fix this? When it happens, IE 11 no longer accepts any mouse input and the browser window has to be refreshed.